# Close a dialog on clicking CANCEL button ignoring EN_KILLFOCUS

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, message-map

I have a CEdit field in my dialog where I have implemented `EN_KILLFOCUS`, so when the user enters invalid data a warning message is displayed when the focus moves away from this field and the focus returns to the CEdit field so that the user can enter proper data. If the user enters invalid data and clicks on the CANCEL button, then also a warning message is displayed which is undesirable because the user is anyway trying to cancel his actions. I have tried implementing PostQuitMessage when the user clicks on CANCEL button, but this closes the entire application. I want only my dialog to close when the user clicks CANCEL button. Is there any way that I can close the dialog instantly after I click on CANCEL button. This is the code that I tried.

```
void CMARPropWnd::OnParentNotify(UINT message, LPARAM lParam)   
{
    CCDialog::OnParentNotify(message, lParam); 
    // TODO: Add your message handler code here 
    CPoint ptButtonDown(LOWORD(lParam),HIWORD(lParam)); 
    if ((message == WM_LBUTTONDOWN)  && (ChildWindowFromPoint(ptButtonDown) == GetDlgItem(eMARPropWndCancelBtnId))) 
    { 
        PostQuitMessage(0);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Vaidation is already implemented in a different project. I cannot do anything about it :)  Will really appreciate if there is some solution

Comment: Have you tried posting a WM_CLOSE message?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
OnCancel();
```

instead of PostQuitMessage(0);

Note that OnCancel() is a virtual method of CDialog, so this is the "most correct", and will do any special code that may override the default CDialog behavior.

Comment: Actually OnCancel tries to close the dialog by implementing EndDialog(). EndDialog moves the keyboard focus away from the CEdit field and this again makes the validation to happen and displays the warning message which is not needed here. So is there something other than EndDialog that could be used here ?

Comment: Add a bool member `m_bInsideOnCancel`, setting it to `false` in the ctor.  Override `OnCancel()`, set `m_bInsideOnCancel` to `true`, then chain back to call `BASE_CLASS::OnCancel();`.  In your EN_KILLFOCUS notification method, make sure `!m_bInsideOnCancel` before you do any processing.  Would that work?

Comment: Thanks for the response but actually EN_KILLFOCUS is implemented in another project and I don't have access to modify it. Is there no way I can handle it without adding this member variable ?